# Global timer countdown in MVC4

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

### Description of what Im trying to achieve :

I have a countdown of 30 minutes, on my website, everybody can see it, and I need to access this variable from every view I have (including the Layout Page).

Once the 30 min. coutdown is complete, I have to make 2 things :

1. call a function (doing something in the DB)
2. check from the result of this function, and then to decide if I want to reset the timer back to 30 min. or have an "extra time" of 5 min. (and then return to the call function all over again ...)

---

Is there any way to make a timer countdown in MVC ?
(Im doing it on the BaseClass, so every page will have access on this code)

I need my timer to have a function of "Whats my current Time?" and knowing when the timer is on 0, so I will reset the timer all over again (but with different time this time..)

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? Does this timer need to be impervious to app_pool restarts? If so, you will want/need an external service (external to your webapp) such as a windows service. Please post more info so we can help.

Comment: this is MVC4 , and I'll use the timer as a static prop

Comment: If you use the timer as a static property of your base controller or your MvcApplication class then your timer will die when the app pool recycles. Are you sure this is OK for the functionality you are after? Perhaps a quick description of what you are ultimately trying to achieve might help us better

Comment: sure, here you go. (look on the original question)

Comment: make a singletone class that handle the job. initialize here in application_start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely want to use an external service for this. There are a few things to consider. What if no request is being processed when the 30 mins is up? What if the app pool recycles during the countdown? Does it matter that the counter has been reset?

Is the webapp all on one machine? or is load-balanced across several servers? If the app is on one machine, then I would write the logic into a windows service and call that from my webapp to check the current countdown status. I would also write the functionality to call the database into this service. If you are in a load-balanced environment (like Azure) then consider a separate server to host the service so that it can be accessed by all webservers.